# WooCommerce basket icon showing as square

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with WordPress + WooCommerce & when I am logged in the icon for the shopping cart work fine, if I am logged out like a regular user they show up as a square like an icon is not recognized.

I have narrowed it down to this:

In my functions.php I have added this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles');
function child_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'reset-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ovr.css', array());
}
```

Which loads in a custom CSS file that I have created. If I remove this then the icons show up as they should, at first I thought it must be some CSS blocking the icons but it doesn't make sense as they show up fine when I am logged in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely in the **ovr.css** file you use a different font than the icons.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fontawesome icon try to add this to the icon's class in the css file:

```
font-family: "fontawesome";
```

Or if this didn't work use 'font-family: "fontawesome" !important;', or try any other font-family which your fontawesome support (by version).

See more: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements